# Creating a GUI with OOP languages?

Tags: user-interface

I have programmed in Java some and tried to use net-beans to create a user interface.  I know only a little about the C languages, though, from what I understand creating a UI can be difficult.  I mainly work with javascript now and find it a whole lot easier to get a functional application going. This is primarily because creating a GUI is extremely easy in html.  I can hand-code an advanced html UI, where with Java and net-beans I had a hard time just using the IDE to create a simple layout.

So is there alternative language for Java or C that would work as kind of frontend for creating an interface?  Or are there better IDE's then net beans?  I haven't used .net's visual studio; is it any easier then net beans?  Also, is there a language that is specifically for UI development that can work with any of the major languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look at one of the standard gui toolkits. Your options are (among others) Qt, GTK+, wxWidgets, Tk.

If your GUI isn't too advanced than you could try creating it with one of the design tools available. For me the Qt designer usually does what I need and you can easily change/modify the generated GUI from the code so it can be used as a template.

Comment: moreover, I think qt lets you use a kind of css.

Comment: That's correct Aif. You can style your application a little using some CSS. You can even use RichText markup (HTML) in a lot of elements like labels and such.

Comment: And now, with Qt Quick, creating user interfaces became more flexible, a bit like hand-coded HTML.

Answer (score 1):

[WPF](http://windowsclient.net/) is a nice framework on the Microsoft side of things. XAML markup is pretty easy to pick up and the built-in designer in Visual Studio isn't bad. It's been my experience that C# is not too difficult to learn if you have a grasp on Java.